# How to str.replace on object?

Tags: python, python-2.7, nuke

Inside The Foundry's Nuke there is a class called `Node`.

Say I have a "node" object called `Item1`

If I `print Item1` I get

```
#Print Item1
# Result:

maskChannelMask alpha
maskChannelInput none
inject false
invert_mask false
message Hello There
```

I want to replace "Hello There" with "Goodbye"
My guess was

```
Item1 = str(Item1.replace("Hello There", "Goodbye")
```

but that obviously converts it to a string.

So how would I go about replacing content of the "node" object, and keep it a node object?

Comment: So the node object has a field called 'message'?

Comment: Can you add the output of `dir(Item1)` to your question.  It might help everyone understand what kind of object node is.

Comment: Sounds like you need to read the [node metadata chapter](http://docs.thefoundry.co.uk/nuke/63/pythondevguide/metadata.html) of the python dev guide..

Answer (score 0):

You can perform replace on message (assuming that message is field of "node" object):

```
Item1.message = Item1.message.replace("Hello there", "Goodbye")
```

Comment: I have doubts about [`replace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) being the right way to go about this

Comment: Sadly it isnt. "AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'message'"

Comment: So we need more informations about that "node" class.
Jason Sperske: I've edited my answer, thanks.

Comment: Your edit makes sense, but I was actually commenting on if calling replace to outright replace a string is really what the questioner meant.  It looked like `Item1.message = 'Goodbye'` would suffice, though your code would only replace the string if it originally contained the text "Hello there" :)

Comment: Sorry, I automatically thought about replacing texts in longer strings ;)

Comment: http://docs.thefoundry.co.uk/nuke/63/pythonreference/nuke.Node-class.html could be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Printing a `nuke.Node` instance dumps out a string representation of that node, showing the knob names and their current value.

The `message` part refers to a knob called `message, whcih you access by doing`Item1['message']`, you can then call`value()`or`setValue()` on this.

So, to modify the value, you'd query the original value, do the string replacement, then update the node with `setValue`

```
original = Item1['message'].value()
updated = original.replace("Hello There", "Goodbye")
Item1['message'].setValue(original)
```

This is covered in the Nuke Python Dev Guide, specifically in the ["Getting Started" section](http://docs.thefoundry.co.uk/nuke/63/pythondevguide/basics.html#assigning-variables)